# Accessing objects data with help of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

I have below scenario. i.e i have a object as below.

```
    var x= {
        "item": {
            "count": 6,
            "type": "product",
            "max": "100",
        },

    }

var loadJson = JSON.parse(x);
```

now if i have a string like.

`var y="item"` how can i access `loadJson.y.count` , I am getting error saying y is undefined.

Comment: now it is different, I am getting an error undefined if i want to access in above scenario(i have a string data)

Comment: there is no x, you parsed the variable x, and set it to loadJson.  so now `loadJson.item` is item.  and `loadJson.item.count` is to get to count.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i have a scenario where i will get variable from "y" which is string and i need to fetch the value using variable y,This scenario i am facing issue.Please suggest.